# Converting conversations IRC logs with regex?

Tags: regex, irc, reformat, reformatting

So here I have IRC logs which come from a BNC in the format of (where [AA:BB:CC] is not the actual time, only the time of loading):

```
[AA:BB:CC] <Person1> [re:al:ts] BLAH BLAH BLAH
[AA:BB:CC] <Person2> [an:ot:he] BLAH BLAH BLAH
[AA:BB:CC] <Person3> [rr:ea:lt] BLAH BLAH BLAH
[AA:BB:CC] <Person4> [im:es:tp] BLAH BLAH BLAH
```

I'd like to convert it to:

```
[re:al:ts] <Person1> BLAH BLAH BLAH
[an:ot:he] <Person2> BLAH BLAH BLAH
[rr:ea:lt] <Person3> BLAH BLAH BLAH
[im:es:tp] <Person4> BLAH BLAH BLAH
```

Is this technically possible? I see that [AA:BB:CC] could easily be removed, but how would I retain the real timestamps and move them to the /beginning/ of the line without removing the "blah blah blah" or ""s? To be honest, I'm not really well-versed in regex...

Thanks :)
Maple

Comment: Am I right in thinking timestamps are of the form `hh:mm:ss`? Cuuld you provide a real example? Unless you want me to guess what the contents of your file are.

Answer (score 2):

An example to solve:

```
perl -pe 's/^\[..:..:..](.*)(\[..:..:..]) (.*)/$2$1$3/' <<EOT
[AA:BB:CC] <Person1> [re:al:ts] BLAH BLAH BLAH
[AA:BB:CC] <Person2> [an:ot:he] BLAH BLAH BLAH
[AA:BB:CC] <Person3> [rr:ea:lt] BLAH BLAH BLAH
[AA:BB:CC] <Person4> [im:es:tp] BLAH BLAH BLAH
EOT
```

Output:

```
[re:al:ts] <Person1> BLAH BLAH BLAH
[an:ot:he] <Person2> BLAH BLAH BLAH
[rr:ea:lt] <Person3> BLAH BLAH BLAH
[im:es:tp] <Person4> BLAH BLAH BLAH
```

If AA, BB, CC, ... are numbers, then use `\d\d` instead of `..` in perl regex.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realise you didn't have to escape the closing "]". The code a little more concise in perl...

Comment: @bmorris591 Yes, -p and -n args reduces the overhead a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use multi-line matching, try this regex:

```
/\[.*?]( <.*?> )\[(.*?)]/g
```

and you would replace by:

```
"[$2]$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets make a few assumptions first.

1. Timestamps in of the form [hh:mm:ss], seconds/minutes under 10 are expressed as 01 etc.
2. The person string does not contain a "["

Then the following regex will work:

```
^\[\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\]([^\[]++)(\[\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\])(.*)$
```

Here is a test case written in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] strings = {"[AA:BB:CC] <Person1> [re:al:ts] BLAH BLAH BLAH",
        "[12:12:11] <Person2> [14:10:25] BLAH BLAH BLAH",
        "[12:12:11] <Person3> [14:10:25] BLAH BLAH BLAH",
        "[12:12:11] <Person4> [14:10:25] BLAH BLAH BLAH"};
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\[\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\]([^\\[]++)(\\[\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\])(.*)$");
    for(final String string : strings) {
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        if(matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2) + matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(3));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[14:10:25] <Person2>  BLAH BLAH BLAH
[14:10:25] <Person3>  BLAH BLAH BLAH
[14:10:25] <Person4>  BLAH BLAH BLAH
```